# How can I delete every hourly backup except the 24 most recent ones?

Tags: linux, bash, backup, nas, posix

I used to have a server with hourly/daily backups, all readily available thanks to [this nice tutorial](http://www.mikerubel.org/computers/rsync_snapshots/). Unfortunately, said server fried and I now have to make my backups on a NAS which doesn’t run<sup>1</sup> my favorite linux flavor. It so happens that my previous solution do not run on said NAS because its binary offer less options.

However, I find that `hourly.n` are terrible names for backups. I would rather have them formatted as `horaire_YYYY_MM_DD_HHhMM`<sup>2</sup> so that users immediately know which backup was made when.

I want to keep 24 hourly backups before keeping only daily backups. Please note that I do *not* want to keep hourly backups for the 24 last hours only; if for some reason<sup>3</sup> a few backups were skipped, I would still want to keep 24 backups, even if some are more than one-day-old.

Here is how I used to proceed:

```
        ls --format=single-column --directory --sort=time $(scheme "*") \
            | tail --lines +$((backup_count + 1)) \
            | xargs --verbose --delimiter="\n" rm -rf
```

`scheme` is just a function which ensure the correct formatting of backup directory, including date. Here used with `*` to match every hourly backup. `ls` lists every hourly backup directory, sorted backwards by creation time<sup>4</sup>, `tails` discards the 24 newest and `xargs` deletes the ones remaining.

I now must ensure I only use POSIX options. I first went with:

```
ls -1 -d -t "$(scheme \*)" \
             | tail -n +$((backup_count + 1)) \
             | sed 's/\n/\0/g' \
             | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

but `ls` does not expand the `*`; I replaced it with `find`, but have no idea how to sort the results by date of creation. I wonder if I could also bypass `tail` completely thanks to `find`, which probably is the right tool for the task anyway.

How can I run a command on every hourly backup which is not one of the 24 last?

---

1. Well, it probably could, but that would imply discarding all the user-friendly tools and support delivered by the NAS provider, which we don’t want.
2. `horaire` instead of `hourly` because the users and I are french speakers.
3. The backup server has to go offline for one day because it needs to be moved, e.g.
4. Alphabetical order could probably do as well if the dates ignore summer time, which would be an unfortunate but acceptable compromise.

Comment: You probably should use `find` instead of `ls`. With find you can easily get a list of files over 24 hours old, instead of having to parse output of ls. Additionally, parsing output of ls is [not recommended](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls).

Comment: @SamiLaine As I said in the (very last line of a long) question, that’s the direction I’m going now. It would probably also let me avoid issues any quoting mess because of spaces in filenames. But, as I wrote, I don’t want a list of directories older than 24 hours old, I want a list of (anything but) the latest 24 directories, whatever their age. If, for any reason, backups stop for more than 24 hours, I still want a “latest hourly backup” to `rsync --link-dest` with, e.g.

Comment: Also, the NAS *does* come with Python installed. Switching to it *would* probably be a good idea.

Comment: I once wrote a small program to do precisely this: select which backups to delete based on their date and a set of configurable rules. See the script `bu-rmselect` at https://www.jaapeldering.nl/software/